# PHP/HTML: trouble utilizing Explode with data gotten from pulldown menu

Tags: php, html, menu, explode

so i'm trying to use a pull-down menu(html) that's populated by data taken from a data base. this part works fine. i got the menu to display everything i needed it to. the problem is that i also need to use the values that this menu contains for mysqli insert statements. here's the code

```
<form action="processStatisticUpdate.php" method="post">
            <table style="margin: 0px auto; border: 0px; border-collapse:separate;">
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right; background: lightblue;">Name (Last, First)</td>
<!--            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" size="50" maxlength="500"/></td>  -->
                <td><select name="name_ID" required>
                  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose player's name here</option>
```

note the tha name of the menu is name_ID

the next bit of code is where i actually make the options.:

```
echo "<option value=\"$T_ID\">$name</option>";
```

where $T_ID is gotten from a bind_result and name is the concatenation of two more of such values. this same state will be looped over several times as its in a while($stmt->fetch()) statement. so it basically populates this section of the HTML with options.

now as i've said, i know these parts work because the pull-down menu on my web page actually works, but for some reason i have trouble with this next bit, which is part of a required file.

```
require('home_page.php');
// create short variable names
$name       = preg_replace("/\t|\R/",' ',$_POST['name_ID']);
$time       = preg_replace("/\t|\R/",' ',$_POST['time']);
$points     = (int) $_POST['points'];
$assists    = (int) $_POST['assists'];
$rebounds   = (int) $_POST['rebounds'];
// convert name and time into separate variables to fit into database
list($Lname, $Fname) = explode(",", $name); // <- experiencing issues here
```

so the problem i'm having is this error code :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp64\www\hmw3\processStatisticUpdate.php on line 10
```

now i looked this up and it appears to be because the value it receives isn't always (maybe not ever) in the format its expecting but i know for a fact it is, since its supposed to be passed in from $name which is made like this.

```
$name = implode(',',[$Name_last, $Name_first]);
```

back on the homepage. I have no idea whats going on or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will occur when $name being passed to explode does not include a comma and so there are insufficient values in the resultant array for the list assignment.

This is probably because your select input will send the **value** of the selected option to PHP so $_POST['name_ID'] will contain a $T_ID, not a $name as you expect.

Comment: oh....OH! oohohohoho, wow, i did not know that last part, wow...i just edited my code and it works now, that was so silly, thank you very VERY much.

Comment: Glad to help out.